# Error while build an app in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having some trouble to deploy my app on my device. The code works fine with the iOS simulator, but when I try to run it on my iOS device it shows the following error:

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppTests normal arm64
    cd "/Users/user/Documents/Demo app/App"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app/App -framework XCTest -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/AppTests.build/Objects-normal

ld: file not found: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app/App
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can't understand what's wrong with my app. I searched on the web to try to understand what's wrong and I found the following solution:

- Check if I import .h files and not .m files --> In my app all ok
- Check the correct Framework --> In my app I use only the default Framework, so no problem
- Check the Library search path --> In my app there are no problem about this

So what's the problem? Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: try to remove DerivedData folder from XCode, clean and build project.

Comment: I tried to remove this folder: `/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dpvmxvpfnnbticgaudzudnxmumqu`, then clean and build project, but I've the same issue

Comment: this is kind of unexpected issue, sometimes this work.